# How do I override a method?

Tags: c#, winforms

I created an OnPaint event of my button,which I lately tried to override,but I failed

My code:

```
    protected override void button1_Paint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
    }
```

I get this error: "no suitable method found to override".

What should I do to make the error dissapear,but keep the method as override?

Comment: Overriding an event handler? That seems like a strange thing to do... What is it that you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: I put a comment about what I'm trying to accomplish under your answer.

Comment: Please explain in detail a) what do you want to override; b) why do you want to override it? I get the feeling that the whole cause of the problem is that you are trying to override where you don't actually need to override anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the method is not virtual, you can't override it. If you can't override it, there is no point in trying to keep the `override` keyword.

If you want to shadow the method, you use the `new` keyword instead of `override`.

Comment: I'm asking,because of the third answer in this question -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/946150/why-does-text-drawn-on-a-panel-disappear made by BFree.I can't make it override

Comment: I see. Then you have to create a class that inherits from Panel, so that you can override the OnPaint method.

Answer (score 3):

The method that you want to override is probably called OnPaint, not button1_Paint. Change the method declaration so it looks like this instead:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) { }
```

Note though that this code should be in a subclass of the class from which you want to override the method. If you place this method in a form, it will handle that form's painting.

Answer (score 1):

In your base-class, you need to declare the method as `virtual`

example:

```
public class Person
{
    public virtual void DoSomething()
    {
        // do something here
    }
}

public class Employee : Person
{
    public override void DoSomething()
    {
        base.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

Perhaps this can help you out?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
    }

    private void button1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {

    }


}
```

Comment: This is the base class,its placed in Form1 class and the designer is also inherited from Form1.

Comment: @John: if it's in the base class, what do you want to override?

Answer (score 0):

You should declare the method in the base class as `virtual` in order to be able to override it.

Answer (score 0):

you override methods coming from other classes. To keep the method you'll have to put it in a child class and call it from there.

do you have the override in the same class as the original method? if so, just merge the functions and remove the override.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have something like this now:

```
public class MyButton : Button {
    public MyButton() {
        this.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(MyButton_Paint);
    }

    void MyButton_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {
        //your code
    }
}
```

If you inherited from a button you should use this code:

```
public class MyButton : Button {
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pevent) {
        base.OnPaint(pevent);
    }
}
```